# Make new terms in term groups when making a new page

Tags: navigation, managed-metadata, metadata, wiki

I'm working with a Enterprise WIKI and are using managed metadata for navigation in quick launch. I have set up a term set with term groups. Inside each group there are terms like this:-

- Term group 1

  - Term 1
  - Term 2

    - Term 2.1
- Term group 2

I have set up the same system in Pages with folders. Right now it looks correct.

When making a new page, the term are made automatically and are placed over Term *group 1*.

What I want is to link the structure in Pages with the term set, so when a new page is made in a folder, it automatically makes a new term inside the correct term group.

So if I make a new page on the page linked to Term 2, it makes a new term, Term 2.2, in that group.

I'm not experienced with SharePoint, but haven't found any similar problems like this on the web!!